# Mutating a list while looping

Tags: python

I am trying to loop through a list and mutate the list I'm working on by making a copy. I am getting the following error but am unsure how to fix:

```
     52 def match_jugglers(list_of_jugglers):
     53     while len(list_of_jugglers) > 0:
---> 54         jugglers = list_of_jugglers[:]
     55         for juggler in jugglers:
     56             for preference in juggler.preferences:

TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1: list_of_jugglers is a deque(), sorry should have mentioned that.
UPDATE 2: Um, so I'm an idiot in thinking I could slice a deque() and make a copy -- was still thinking list in my head (thus the original description).

Comment: I don't have the error, neither on Python 2.7 nor 3.3

Comment: It works on OS X 10.8 with Python 2.7.2

Comment: try `jugglers = list(list_of_jugglers)`

Comment: Are you sure you are using a list and not any other collection?

Comment: Is list_of_jugglers an iterator, or a real list? You can't slice an iterator.

Comment: itertools.islice might help you